# How can I  pack 15 different scripts into a single RPM?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I have more then 15 different scripts -  bash, perl etc ( I run the scripts on Red Hat Linux)

I want to pack all scripts by RPM. How to do that?

For example I want to do

```
 rpm -Uvh all_scripts_pack
```

and then to get all script under `/root/New_DIR` (the rpm need also to create the `New_DIR`directory)

Answer (score 1):

rpms should never touch user's home directories; place the scripts in `/usr/sbin` instead.

Put all the scripts in a tarball then use one of the many rpm creation guides to construct the spec file.

Answer (score 0):

I fear it will be impossible to actually answer this question fully. There is however a lot of documentation out there on this subject.

To begin with, I'd suggest taking a look at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/A_Short_RPM_Tutorial Its an very quick guide that helps you build an rpm for a "hello world" binary. Its slightly more complicated than you need, what with the make's & make installs but I'm hoping you can remove the steps you don't need and modify the rest accordingly.

If I find an example for packaging bash scripts I'll edit my answer but surprisingly I haven't found one yet.